# Which tools or libraries support execution of containment queries for trees?

Tags: search, graph, tree, xquery

I've been developing an implementation of a containment query language with quite limited documentation and no reference implementation to use as a guide. 
The containment language queries tree structures for existence of tree patterns, and is has a syntax like this:

```
A CONTAINS B CONTAINS ((C contains A) AND (C CONTAINS D))
```

A, B, C and D are types of tree nodes, or with a more generic view, they're labels of nodes. 
A CONTAINS B means A has a child B somewhere below it in the tree.

The implementation needs to return all matching subtrees of a tree instance queried with the statement above (which represents a partially defined tree). It also needs to consider combinations of occurrences of patterns, for example, in the query above, if C has 2 A instances below it, then C-A1 with C-D and C-A2 with C-D are two different matches etc..

I've designed my own solution, but I don't have anything that I could use as a reference, or even better in regression tests alongside my code to make sure that my implementation acts consistently and correctly.

The most tricky bit is the logical operators in the query language. I'm about to look into XQuery with XML as a reference implementation (not sure at this point if it can do what I'm trying to do), but I'd love to hear about other options too.  Open source would be great, but even proprietary tools would do the job. Graph DBs which support this type of query, maybe some semantic tools with RDF etc?

Comment: The syntax example given above uses the CONTAINS operator in an associative way, although it does not return a result with the same type (boolean) as its operands (trees). What is the expected semantics of A CONTAINS B CONTAINS C? Is it (A CONTAINS B) AND (B CONTAINS C)? Thanks!

Comment: yes, A has a child B node somewhere down its children(s children etc), and this B node has a C node in the same way. It is an ascendant - descendant relation. This is actually  part of my implementation of Archetype Query Language: http://www.openehr.org/wiki/display/spec/Archetype+Query+Language+Description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to make a proof of concept with XQuery (Zorba implementation):

http://www.zorba-xquery.com/html/demo#f63nK4ICLH22

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow! Thanks a lot for the effort!

Comment: You are welcome! It is a bit limited and there might be some mistakes here and there in the code, but I hope it helps you get started. The objects and arrays in the query are part of Zorba's JSONiq extension, they can be useful as intermediate data structures.